# Matching Multiple Words till end of document

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to parse through resumes. I'm trying to find the section labeled Education (or some form of that) and then use rules to define the end of the block.

I currently have a working regex that will find the ~word education and will give me the rest of the document to parse based on rules.

this is my full code that defines the rules

```py
headers = ['experience','projects','work experience','skills 
summary','skills/tools']
for item in resume_paths:
    resume = getText(item)
    resume = resume.replace('\n',' \n ')
    education = re.findall(r'(?i)\w*Education\w*[^?]+', resume)[0].split('\n')
    paragraph = ''
    for line in education[1:]:
         line = line.strip()
         if (line.isupper() == False) and (not line.strip().lower() in headers):
            paragraph += line + '\n'
        else:
            break
    print(resume[:15],paragraph)
```

this is the regex that I'm using

```py
(?i)\w*Education\w*[^?]+
```

I'm running into problems when someone uses the word education multiple times. I want the regex to return a list of all matches to the end of the document and will use rules to determine which one is correct. I've tried removing the + sign to get multiple matches but that gives me both word matches without the rest of the document.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex r'(?i)\w*Education\w*[^?]+' will find 'Education', optionally with extra letters and digits on both sides; then extend that up to the next question mark. \w will not include spaces, punctuation, etc.

I doubt that is what you want. It would get things like:

```
XYZEducationismallly
```

but not

```
Relevant Education
```

[^?] means anything that is not '?'; but I don't see why you would want to scan up to the next question mark (or end of string).

Also, if there's no "?" around (as is likely), that "+" will take everything to the end of the entire source string -- but you probably want to stop at the next heading (if any), such as "Employment History" or whatever.

Really doing this right will be difficult because resumés may be converted to text in many different ways (one obvious example: the lines of the text might each represent one "visual" line from the original, or one "paragraph" block, or even one table cell, if the originator used tables for layout, as in fairly common).

But if you're stuck working from text, probably a clearer and easier way is like:

```
eduSection = []
inEducationSection = False
for line in resume:
    if re.search(r'\bEducation', line): 
        inEducationSection = True
    elif re.search(r'\b(History|Experience|other headingish things)', line):
        inEducationSection = False
    elif inEducationSection:
        eduSection.append(line)
```

If you can pin down what "headings" look like in your data a little
more precisely you'll get much better results. For example:

```
* headings might be all caps, or title caps;
* headings might be  the only things that start in column1
* headings might have no punctuation except final ':'
* headings might be really short compared to (most) other lines
* maybe there are only a few dozen distinct headings that show up often.
```

I'd say the first thing to figure out is how to tell when something is a heading. Once
you have that, the rest is pretty easy.